# What is the correct (regression) test to quantify changes of tumor size of an inhomogeonus data set?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I am analysing a dataset of tumor volumes over time of a tumor that occurs in children. It is hypothesized that the tumors shrink over time and shrink faster the younger you are. The question is how much the tumors decrease on average over time during different ages. I therefore thought I would need some regression and the slope would be my decrease of size over a certain time frame. However the dataset is very inhomogenous. Some tumours were measured several times (e.g., 5 volume measurements over time), others only twice, others 10 times. In addition the measurements happened at different ages. This means one tumor was measured three times, e.g., at 4, 49 and 205 days of age, another was measured two times at 45 and 603 days of age and another at 200 and 412, 415, 490 and 1700 days of age (just example data). So the questions I need to answer are:

- Do tumors shrink in volume over time, if yes, how much on average in my dataset over a certain timeframe.
- Do tumors shrink faster when a patient is within, e.g., his first year of life compared to later years.

I first did a linear regression analysis of different time frames and used every measurement as individual unrelated data point, but I think this doesn't make sense as information of the measurements that are from the same patient is lost and patients and timeframes that have more measurements are overrepresented. But I am not sure if this is a problem. It probably is...  Other regression tests I looked into required that every patient has a value at the very same timepoint (every patient needs a measurment exactly at, e.g., 0 days, 10 days, 20 days, 50 days, etc) and if just one value was missing it gave an error.

What is the correct test I need to do and can do with my type of data?

Answer (score 0):

Your caution about how to proceed is well founded. You do have to take the correlations of observations within individuals into account, and not all regression methods allow for different observation times among individuals.

Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's notes on [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html) discusses the advantages and disadvantages of different approaches to such longitudinal data analysis. Generalized least squares is one good choice, emphasized in that chapter. Those models are sometimes called "growth curve models," emphasizing the relevance to your particular situation. Mixed regression models with individuals treated as random effects provide another approach.

With those methods, individuals with more observations will provide more information to the model than those with fewer observations. But the allowance for correlations within individuals means those individuals won't unduly bias the overall estimates of changes over time or associations with the age of tumor onset.